# DC load flow calculation in various programs

Tags: power

I am using PSSe, PSLF, MATPOWER to run the DC load flow. The modeling for dc load flow should be straightforward i.e., to compute \$\theta\$ in the equation P=B \$\theta\$. Here B is the susceptance matrix and by solving linearly using the injections, we should be able to get the value of \$\theta\$ without any iterations. Infact, that is how it is performed in MATPOWER. However, in programs such as PSLF, when I solve the DC power flow, the choice is given to choose the number of iterations. So, how DC power flow is computed in PSLF, PSSE?

Comment: Is there an EE question here?

Comment: It is an Electrical Engineering question.

Comment: More of a software question it looks like. I'm an electrical engineer and I and having a hard time deciphering these acronyms, I assume they are software programs.

Comment: If an iterative process is suggested, these tools are most likely executing Decoupled Power Flow (I've seen people calling it dc power flow, which is wrong in my understanding). One way to make sure is verify weather you also obtain voltage magnitude values or only voltage angles.